# If a creature takes non-lethal damage, turns into a non-creature, and then back into a creature, does the damage remain?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Sort of a follow-up to [Can Hour of Devastation kill Heliod, Sun-Crowned?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50128/can-hour-of-devastation-kill-heliod-sun-crowned)

Let's say my opponent has two [Benalish Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBenalish%20Marshal%5d) and [Heliod, Sun-Crowned](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeliod%2c%20Sun-Crowned%5d). I cast [Hour of Devastation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHour%20of%20Devastation%5d). Per murgatroid99's answer, Heliod survives.

If my opponent next plays some flash creatures or enchantments that turn Heliod back into a creature, does it still have 5 damage marked on it (+ is no longer indestructible)?

Comment: "If my opponent next plays some flash creatures or enchantments that turn Heliod back into a creature" Are you imagining a scenario in which there's a creature with "target permanent is now a creature"? If you're referring to devotion, Heliod only cares about *your* devotion, not your opponent's.

Comment: @Acccumulation the way the question is worded, Heliod does not care about my devotion, since my opponent is the one controlling Heliod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Damage is marked on a permanent even if it is not a creature.

Comp rules:

> 119.6. Damage marked on a creature remains until the cleanup step, even if that permanent stops being a creature.

Heliod will also not be indestructible in the given scenario, since he was a creature while Hour of Devastation was resolving, which is all that HoD cares about. Changing or losing permanent types does not cause Heliod to regain indestructibility.

Comment: Do you know if the indestructibility remains?

Comment: @Allure updated the answer